# How to go from geth in WSL to vEthernet adaptor to Router

Tags: go, ethereum, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my windows 10 pro laptop I am running geth in WSL. The problem is I can not seem to get reach my wireless router. I am getting a status of not connected to my router. So the web3J calls returns a can not connect. I setup my geth:
geth --http.port "8545" --http.addr "192.168.1.15" --datadir test-chain-dir --http --dev

I setup eth0 to match my address in my ipv4 settings config in my vethernet adaptor
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.15 and the mask ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0

I also add a route ip route add default via 192.168.1.15
So what am I doing wrong? I also tried adding on the windows side the command to setup portproxy.

Is there some definitive instructions somewhere about setting up geth to work within WSL and able to reach out to the router? I wrote some simple code using web3j running on a android phone that is connected on my local network.

Thanks!

Comment: Should I just leave vEthernet settings alone? It seems when I started this journey I was able to download geth, npm from within WSL without doing anything to my network. So the question might narrow down a bit. How do I need to modify/setup my environment so web3j requests reach geth in WSL? Is there some blog or pdf or thread here that mentions all the steps?

Comment: Ok I reinstalled Ubuntu the ran wsl so Ubuntu was running. I tried pinging my website from Ubuntu and pinging worked. So now I am thinking the vEthernet adaptor must be connecting to my wireless adaptor which indicates it is connected to the internet. So I am wondering if I need to reach geth from my smartphone I need to specify the ip of my laptop and the geth port. But I may need to setup port forwarding.